# How to dockerize web application that will be customized?

Tags: docker, war

We ship our web application as WAR file with source code (Java, JSP, Spring config files). Our customers customize our application by changing those files.
A Docker image is supposed to be immutable.
Is it possible to dockerize our application?

Comment: What gets customized and how do you do it?

Comment: Our customers change Java, JSP, Spring config files.

Comment: So you ship as a war file and your customers unpack that file, make changes to whatever they want, then compile and package another war file?

Comment: They change JSP and Spring config files in deployed/unpacked WAR. They change Java, build JAR and WAR, deploy the WAR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can deliver three elements:

- one archive representing your sources
- one representing your app
- one representing a Dockerfiles able to build the first image from the sources, with the sources in its context, able to rebuild the full image.

For a client, dockerize an application after modifying its sources means rebuilding a docker image.

The interest of docker here is that the client doesn't have to know how to build (or what he/she needs to build) your app: everything is configured in the Dockerfile.

Comment: Customers also change JSP and Java at runtime.

Comment: @isobretatel are the JSP part of the sources? If yes, the clients can modify them. Is it possible to fix Java though? That is what docker is know for: encapsulate a fixed execution environment.

Comment: JSPs are compiled at runtime.

Comment: @isobretatel then they can be COPYied by the Dockerfile in order to be present in the resulting image (and compiled at runtime)

Comment: That means that customer will lose his customization after the next upgrade.

Comment: @isobretatel not if the customer rebuild the image.

Comment: JSPs are stored in the image and modified at runtime. How would customer build new image from files in the current image?

Comment: With the deliver I describe, the client can make a docker build.